# Text expansion in Cmder / ConEMU

Tags: macros, conemu, variable-expansion, cmder, doskey

A long time ago, I set my Cmder (ConEMU) to expand "~" to C:\Users\%USERNAME%.

Embarrassingly, I have forgotten how I did it.

Now I'd like to un-do it.

I've checked my alias files and ran "Multifind" searches in the /Cmder directory, but have not been able to identify where I made this change.

The vocabulary word "doskey" stuck in my mind, but using that in my research only lead me in a circle, back to what I was already trying.

If a person wanted to do this, how would they. Since I've done it, were should I check next to un-do it?

Looks like this is version 161206[32].

Comment: I'm not sure if this is now "too localized". My issue was that I was using AutoHotKey to load Cmder and I had created the text expansion there because, for whatever reason, it wasn't working for me otherwise. I edited my AHK script and it took care of my problem.

Comment: It that is Cmder, than expansion was probably configured in clink files.